# How to resolve this error in my Python code: Warning: not all FMESessions that were created were destroyed before shutdown. This may cause instability

Tags: python, modelbuilder, arcgis-pro, fme-form, spatial-etl

I am using the Data Interoperability extension. I created 2 spatial ETL tools and added each to a model in my ArcGIS Pro project. When run manually, both tools and models run just fine but when I put them in a python script using the syntax referenced here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012387, I get this message: `Warning: not all FMESessions that were created were destroyed before shutdown. This may cause instability`.

I've seen on the FME Safe Software technical forum that others have gotten this warning in the past but typically using FME Server. To resolve the warning they have disabled log files and parallel processing, neither of which are not really applicable to data interoperability or my workflow. I am looking for a way to destroy/close down my FME Session using Python.

I am running the Python in VS Code terminal and I am using a floating data interoperability extension license not single use.

Answer (score 3):

I'd be curious if the same message is logged whether you actually run the tool or not.  The tools themselves get executed in their own process, so there is no problem to your script if you get this message -- basically if you got it from the tool execution, it points to a bug in our code that somehow is not cleaning up after itself, but since the tool is shutting down when this message is output, there is no problem.

However, if the message is still seen in this script if you comment out the tool execution, then it means there's something not quite right in our confirmation of license code.

In either case, please do send a note in to support@safe.com with as much information and details as you can provide.

And also in either case, I honestly don't think there will be any ill effect to your script or processing.

Comment: Much appreciated, Dale!  I'm sending the log file from running the workspace directly in FME (not through my python script) to support@safe.com.  I cannot find a log file from the tool when I run it in python.  I do not have the referenced path on my C: drive as indicated here: http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/datainterop/Setting_Options_for_the_Data_Interoperability_Extension.htm.  This may be because I'm running Pro not Desktop.